# Ubuntu doesn't detect displays

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

After some updates my screen resolution is 640x480 (or maybe even lower) and there is no option to change it. I can't tell what exactly I updated, I remember that I've installed `linuxbrew-wrapper`. When I open Settings/Devices/Displays there is unknown display, no resolution options.
my config:
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
GeForce GTX 750 Ti
I have 3 screens DVI connection
I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

but this command ends with

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-455 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-compute-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-455 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-455:i386 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-455:i386 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-455:i386 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-455:i386 (= 455.45.01-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

After a week, a new update of nvidia drivers was available. After installing it the problem solved.